# Iterate in page and find all checked checkbox by jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have many checkbox in my page and i need to iterate in all checkbox and check is it checked or not.

my html

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="JqueryIdList1" value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" id="JqueryIdList2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="JqueryIdList3" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="JqueryIdList4" value="4" />
```

i got a code but that will not solve my purpose. so please tell me how to achieve it by jquery.

Comment: If you have code, post it so we can correct it.

Comment: This is really difficult to answer as-is. Please post all of your code, including what you have tried, so we can see where you need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `:checkbox` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) returns all checkboxes on page
- `:checked` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) returns only checked elements
- `is` [method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns true if current element matches the selector, false otherwise

All together:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //do something if checkbox is checked
    } else {
        //do something if checkbox is not checked
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sList = "";
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    sList += "(" + $(this).val() + "-" + (this.checked ? "checked" : "not checked") + ")";
});
console.log (sList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // First way 
    $('#checkBox').attr('checked'); 
    // Second way 
    $('#edit-checkbox-id').is(':checked'); 
    // Third way for jQuery 1.2
    $("input[@type=checkbox][@checked]").each( 
        function() { 
           // Insert code here 
        } 
    );
    // Third way == UPDATE jQuery 1.3
    $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each( 
        function() { 
           // Insert code here 
        } 
    );
```